# commetChat cordova-plugin-cccometchat CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod MessageSDKFramework (~> 7.0.10)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3, cometchat

cordova-plugin-cccometchat plugin working fine in android version but when i build ios version getting following errors

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MessageSDKFramework":
  In Podfile:
    MessageSDKFramework (~> 7.0.10)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `MessageSDKFramework (~> 7.0.10)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

Comment: Often I have to use pod install [app name].  Cordova often does not download the pods for you.

Comment: After pod update (platforms/ios folder ) getting above errors

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by Opening `xcodeproject` file and set target `ios` version to `10` and then `pod install` or `pod update`.